# EAS build failed: Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information

Tags: reactjs, gradle, build, expo, eas

I try to setup Google Ads in my React Native App (Android). i followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myDDG54OvkE

After >>> npm i expo-dev-client

and paste this code in my app.json-file:

```js
"react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
```

(of course replaced the default value with the right one)

i get the following error message if i hover above: Property 'react-native-google-mobile-ads' is not allowed
and if i try >>> npx expo-doctor it cant detect any issues.

then:
eas login

> > > npx eas-cli build --profile development
> > > i get this error [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYGGP.png)

iam running out of ideas because i also cant find any useful answers if i ask google.
thanks for all answers

tried:
npx expo-doctor
un- and reinstall expo-dev-client and react-native-google-mobile-ads